# Old Three.js demo won't work in Chrome now

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I have this small demo with Three.js, that stopped working suddenly for Chrome (but works for Firefox), which is weird because I am using the same version of the library as before (r47), so new changes in Three.js shouldnt affect my demo.

Has Chrome changed his behaviour or introduced bugs with WebGL?

Demo: http://www.enriquemorenotent.com/demos/cube/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Chrome has changed its behaviour... I'm aware of this problem but I haven't figured out what is it that started failing.

If you update the demo to a newer three.js it should work again though.

Comment: Oh, mrdoob itself :) If I update to the latest three.js, will I need to change the code of the demo?

Comment: Yes, quite a bit, sadly. Use the [migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) page as reference.

Comment: According to the WebGL Inspector it's getting errors in the shaders. Example: `Uniforms with the same name but different type/precision: renderType`.

Comment: This is a bug in Firefox. It should be failing those as well. Here's the conformance test.  http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/misc/shader-with-global-variable-precision-mismatch.html

Comment: @gman, I wonder if the browser could "fix" those shaders (throwing a warning/error) to maintain support?

Comment: I have fixed the issue with the newest Three.js version.Thank you, Mr. Doob. One warning, you havent documented BoxGeometry! Please fix ;) Here is the demo (http://www.enriquemorenotent.com/demos/cube/) and here is the post I wrote (http://enriquemorenotent.com/three-js-building-a-cube-with-different-materials-on-each-face/)

Comment: Funny thing is still fails in Firefox, apparently must be that bug gman talked about...

Comment: @mrdoob, I think the decision was made that it was best to fix it now than let it linger. There's a spec, OpenGL ES 2.0, as much as possible they'd like to stick with it. That includes enforcing its limits otherwise you write one place where things are not strict and it fails somewhere else where things are strict. What should they have done? Re-write the shaders to match where it's vec2 in one & vec3 in the other? The fact that some drivers lets this pass is bad but how would they work around the issue on drivers that don't? Better to just require stuff that works everywhere by being strict.

Comment: @gman I understand... Maybe I can try to write a patch that fixes three.js in those old projects instead then :)